# Vim: how to append the content of a variable to a file?

Tags: file, vim, editor, text-editor, vi

I was wondering: is it possible to write the content of a variable (in my case, the last search) to a file **with a command**?

I tried the following:

```
:echo @/ >> /tmp/foo.txt
:@/w /tmp/foo.txt
```

But that didn't work. Any idea on what is the correct way to do this?

Comment: `:echo <C-r>/ >> /tmp/foo.txt` but… why do you want to do that?

Comment: What do you mean by `<C-r>`? Why are you adding a special key combination inside a command? By the way, your command does not work as taken literally: `E15: Invalid expression: <C-r>/ >> /tmp/foo.txt` This command is part of a bigger project: I need to communicate some stuff to an external program

Comment: `<C-r>` means "press ctrl+r". See `:h c_ctrl-r`.

Comment: but I need a `:` command, so I cannot insert special key combinations there. Did you try yourself the command you wrote? To me it gives the exception that I pasted in the previous comment.

Comment: I don't need to try it. You type `:!echo `, then you press Ctrl+R followed by `/`, then you type `>> /tmp/foo.txt` and you press Enter.

Comment: Oh, now I get it. It's going to expand the variable in the command line. That's not what I need, because, to keep it short, I need to automate it, for example to create a keybinding.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114609/discussion-between-fstab-and-romainl).

Comment: That's what you asked, though.

Comment: Okay if you want real automation bind something to this NASTY macros i just recorded for you.
`/kVy:q:!echo " >> history.log`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alternative solution to romain’s proposal is to use the `redir` command which redirects messages to a file.  As described in `:help redir`,

> The messages which are the output of commands are written to that file,
>   until redirection ends.

To append the contents of the search register, run the following sequence of commands:

```
redir >> /tmp/foo.txt
echo @/
redir END
```

This sequence could be turned into a function and/or used as a key mapping.